# Command line switch to prevent Inno Setup installer from creating desktop Icon

Tags: inno-setup, silent-installer, balsamiq

I am trying to create a silent install for Balsamiq Mockups which appears to be created using Inno Setup compiler.

As part of the standard silent install it creates a desktop shortcut which I wish to prevent.

Does anyone know the relevant command line switch to prevent the desktop icon being created?

I have tried using `/MERGETASKS="!desktopicon"` but this does not work. Is there a way to list what Tasks and their variable names that are being run/used by the install process?

Answer (score 2):

To find out task names, run the installer with the `/SAVEINF=path`, to get it save its settings to an `.inf` file. If you check the task, you are interested in, during the installation, you will see this directive in the `.inf` file:

```
Tasks=thetask
```

Now you have the task name, you can use with [`/MERGETASKS`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=MERGETASKS).

---

Another way is to decompile the installer to see the `[Tasks]` section.

You can use e.g. [Inno Setup Unpacker](https://innounp.sourceforge.net/) or [innoextract](https://github.com/dscharrer/innoextract).

---

Though it's also possible the option does not have any task associated.

What is unfortunately this case (there are no task checkboxes in the installer), and even more.

When you decompile the installer, you will see that it does not create the shortcut itself (so no Inno Setup switch helps here). The shortcut is probably created by `Balsamiq_Mockups_AIR.exe` executed by the installer with `-desktopShortcut` switch:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\Balsamiq_Mockups_AIR.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-silent -desktopShortcut -programMenu"; \
  BeforeInstall: "UninstallPreviousVersion"
```