# Inno Setup: Disable desktop icon and autostart entry via command line parameter

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating an desktop icon and an autostart entry with an Inno Setup script like this:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commonstartup}\abc"; Filename: "{app}\xyz.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: createonlyiffileexists; Tasks: StartMenuEntry
Name: "{commondesktop}\abc"; Filename: "{app}\xyz.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconIndex: 0; Tasks: desktopicon

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"
Name: "StartMenuEntry"; Description: "{cm:AutoStartProgram}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AutoStartProgramGroupDescription}"
```

Some users want to run my setup.exe from the command line. They want to add a parameter for silent installation */VERYSILENT* and a parameter for disabling the desktop icon and the autostart entry.

Is that possible with a command line parameter? If not: What else is possible to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`/TASKS`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=TASKS) or better [`/MERGETASKS` command-line switches](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=MERGETASKS) to alter the default task selection.

Particularly, to disable particular task, use `/MERGETASK=!taskname`:

```
mysetup.exe /VERYSILENT /MERGETASKS=!desktopicon,!StartMenuEntry
```

---

Related question: [Command line switch to prevent Inno Setup installer from creating desktop Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44566726/850848)